# Transfer WiFi to a PC using a ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I have a PC with no WiFi adapter. Is there a way to achieve such a setup where the ESP8266 is connected to the PC with a serial connection and the PC can connect to the internet using the WiFI of the ESP8266? In other words, using the ESP8266 as a WiFi proxy of the PC?

I know I how to have the ESP8266 access the net and do whatever, like open TCP connections, issue HTTP requests and everything, but I don't know how to tell it to just pass raw data to the serial connection. Is there a way to do that?

### EDIT

I know that it is  a common setup to connect the ESP to a Arduino in order to provide the Arduino with network connectivity. How does it work there?

Comment: Interesting question. Check this (found by googling): https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=157&t=14978

Comment: you will get a WiFi dongle faster then you can implement this on esp8266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of protocol on the serial line that can *encapsulate* IP packets. The most common ones are [SLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol) and [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol). And indeed if you look you can find implementations of both for the ESP; [this one](https://github.com/martin-ger/esp_slip_router) looks promising to me. If you go digging in your OS's dial-up networking support, you should be able to find a SLIP driver there (the ESP might have to pretend to be a modem, accepting some dialing commands and spitting out a `CONNECT` string to get the PC to initiate SLIP). Don't expect good performance *or* ease of use, though. It won't be comparable to using a WiFi adapter connected directly to the PC.

Comment: Why do I need to _encapsulate_ the IP packets and not just forward them between the PC and the ESP? This can be considered a general question about SLIP for example - what is the added value of it?

Comment: @YoavKlein mostly, the ability for the device to know where a packet starts and ends :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your PC has a network driver able to read and write data from the UART.

That's a feature that Windows 2000 Server had.

I doubt that Home or Professional editions of Windows come with such a driver.

Windows Server might have that driver.

Linux might have it.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433228/networking-over-serial-port

Comment: Doesn't this still require dedicated software on both the esp8266 and the pc?

Comment: The PC should have a driver as @Enrico Migliore said. But still, what about the ESP? What program should it run?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry.